# How to resize the image in pdf using iText.layout

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I want to add a logo of my application besides my header in the generated pdf. I am using the below code to do so but the image isn't reducing in size. Any help is appreciated.

```java
// Creating Paragraphs
String heading = "Declaration Letter";
Paragraph head = new Paragraph(heading).setBold().setFontSize(20);

Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph();
paragraph1.add("This is to certify that the Product Serial Number ");

// Adding paragraphs to document
ImageData data = ImageDataFactory.create("img.png");
Image image = new Image(data);
// set Absolute Position
//image.setFixedPosition(450f, 10f);
image.scaleAbsolute(20f, 20f);
// set Scaling
image.setAutoScaleHeight(true);
image.setAutoScaleWidth(true);
    
document.add(image);
document.add(head);
document.add(space);
document.add(space);
document.add(paragraph1);
```

Right now it looks like image1. I want the small icon to the left of the heading.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imaBe.png)

Comment: It looks like you use itext 7. In that case you should add the [tag:itext7] tag. That being said, by setting `AutoScale` settings to `true`, you tell itext to ignore your `scaleAbsolute` call, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that you are using the `com.itextpdf.text.Image` class.
I do not think you are using the `itext` classes.

This would be the correct way to do it with the `Image` class of `itext`:

```java
Image img = Image.getInstance("Path to your image");
img.scaleAbsolute(150,50);
```

Comment: You appear to use itext 5. The op appears to use itext 7.